# Why is my authentication no longer found by users?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a problem. I have authenticated my Zuul Api Gateway. And now this is no longer finding my users. He says invalid credentials. Before that I had a separate login micro service that worked with the same code.
My Main:

```
package sendMessage.netflixzuulapigatewayserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.EnableZuulProxy;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import springSecurity.UserRepository;



@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class NetflixZuulApiGatewayServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NetflixZuulApiGatewayServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My Logging Filter

```
package sendMessage.netflixzuulapigatewayserver;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter;
import com.netflix.zuul.context.RequestContext;
import com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException;

@Component
public class ZuulLoggingFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    private Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());    

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() throws ZuulException {
        RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getRequest();
        logger.info("request ->{} request uri -> {}", request, request.getRequestURI());

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String filterType() {

        return "pre";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {

        return 1;
    }

}
```

My UserDetails

```
package springSecurity;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import springSecurity.User;

public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails{

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private boolean active;
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;


    public MyUserDetails()
    {

    }

    public MyUserDetails(User user) {
        this.userName=user.getUserName();
        this.password=user.getPassword();
        this.active=user.isActive();
        this.authorities =Arrays.stream(user.getRoles().split(","))
                .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return userName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return active;
    }



}
```

My SecurityConfiguration

```
package springSecurity;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests() 
        .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/users").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/user").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/users").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .and().formLogin()
        .and().
        csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder()
    {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why the Users can no longer be found even though it worked before?

Comment: Note that SO is an English speaking site so you might want to translate your first sentences or risk down votes. Further note that if you have any exception stacktraces or other logging output that's relevant here you might want to post it.

Comment: sorry my misstake. I english is not good and i forget to translate ist.